# How do you setup a Google Analytics account for a website that already has the tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics

I have FTP access and am re-designing a website and I want to see historical traffic data from their Google Analytics, but they do not have a Google Analytics Account and can not get in touch with their last web person who set it up.

The tracking code has been in place for several years.  There are a lot of articles about how to add Google Analytics code to a website but how do you setup a Google Analytics account with tracking code that is already there?

Comment: This would best be asked in the Webmasters forum as it is not related to coding. But to comment, you would need to have access to the account in order to access the reports. I don't believe there's any other way around it. You can still use the same account ID, but it would be useless without getting at the reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to ask person who set it up. But if it is impossible - here is the article, which help You - http://savvydealer.com/reclaim-your-google-analytics-account/

This is the only one way.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options,

1. Ask for the Authoritative person to add you as an Admin, so you can easily get access. If this option may not possible then,
2. You can replace old tracking code with new tracking code.